# Computing gradient w.r.t action, ReLU transfer

Tags: deep-learning, algorithms, gradient-descent, reinforcement-learning

*Foreword : I am new to machine learning and to this community, thank you in advance for your help.*

I am trying to implement this paper from Deepmind [Continuous control for deep reinforcement learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1509.02971v2.pdf)

The NN for the Critic is using 2 hidden layers taking the 'state' as input, an other hidden layer taking the 'action' as input, and then adding both parts of the network, using a ReLU transfer function before computing the output.
So when we feed forward we have something in the lines of :

```
output = ReLU(state * ws1 * ws2 + action * wa1) * wo
```

where `ws1` and `ws2` are the weights for the hidden layers of the 'state', `wa1` the weights for the hidden layer of the 'action', and `wo` the weights for the output layer.

From this I need to compute the gradient of the output w.r.t the action in order to update my Policy Network.

What bothers me is that ReLU function. **What am I supposed to do with it** when computing the derivative w.r.t the action as what is inside this function does not depend solely on the action?

---

And a noob question while I am at it : 
If there was no ReLU transfer function, say the output would be calculated that way :

```
output = (state * ws1 * ws2 + action * wa1) * wo
```

would the derivative of the output w.r.t the action equal to `wa1 * wo`?

Comment: It would help if you could point us to the specific line/equation of the paper that you're trying to implement. Answer to your first question: You take the derivative of a ReLU in a piecewise manner, so that it's $0$ from $(-\infty,0)$ and $1$ from $[0,\infty)$, and apply the chain rule as necessary. Answer to your second question: If the only variable in that equation with any dependence on the action is the action itself, then yes, the derivative is equal to wa1*wo

Comment: @jon_simon . The algorithm I am implementing can be found page 5 of the paper, called `Algorithm 1 DDPG algorithm`. They say I need to `Update the actor policy using the sampled gradient`, and for so I need to calculate the gradient of the Critics' output w.r.t the action. What do you mean by "piecewise manner"?